# Заставить JavaScriptSerializer сериализовать выборочно

Tags: c#

Есть класс

```
class A {
  public int A {get;set;}
  public int B {get;set;}
  public int C {get;set;}
}
```

и код

```
System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer =
  new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
serializer.Serialize();
string JSON = serializer.Serialize(new A(){A=5,B=7,C=10});
```

Как заставить `System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer` брать только определенные свойства, например на выходе чтоб было без `C`

```
{A:5,B:7}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ScriptIgnoreAttribute Class
>
> Specifies that JavaScriptSerializer will not serialize the public
>   property or public field. This class cannot be inherited.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.scriptignoreattribute(v=vs.110).aspx

```
class A {
  public int A {get;set;}

  public int B {get;set;}

  [ScriptIgnore]
  public int C {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Действительно... Оказывается я не там искал (пытался найти в МСДН в описании класса).